# Vuex $state evaluates correctly from debugger but throws when executed

Tags: vuex, vuex-modules

I'm stumped. I made a quick video showing the debugger evaluates the expression correctly, but when it's stepped over, it throws.

It's from a getter in a vue component accessing `this.$store.state.Obj.value`

https://youtu.be/IRQB1ZWNoGk

**Any suggestions on why would it evaluate correctly in the debugger console but throw when stepped over?**

```
computed: {
  mode: {
    get: () => this.state.$store.getters.mode,
```

The `this` evaluates to my component in the debugger, but throws when it is stepped over it.

FYI. I was trying to follow this pattern for making v-model work https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html#two-way-computed-property

Comment: this.$store.getters.nameItem

Comment: You're committing the mortal sin of fetching a value using the store state directly. You should have a getter function for the value, like Hamilton above suggested, `this.$store.getters.nameItem`. Note that getters in Vuex, even if they are functions, aren't run with (), you just get the value as if it were a value.

Comment: Use getters in vuex, to access data, Documentation. https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html

Comment: Thanks. Yes. I tried `this.$store.getters.nameItem` but the `this.$store` is what's invalid. Even though it evaluates just fine in the debugger.

Has the correct this context in the debugger and I can see the $store, but the code throws.

I'll update the question to show my state declaration. Maybe there's something there?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use arrow function to catch error like this:

```
.catch (e => {
   //Then you can access 'this' here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the disconnect between what the chrome debugger was showing me for the local scope context was confused because it was compiled with babel. The compiler was trying to show me the original source but the actually running javascript was different.

This is what ended up being the solution. It shows **both** ways that worked. First, passing in the state. Second, is using a different notation.

```
computed: {
  ...mapState(['MainMode']),
  mode: {
    get: state => state.MainMode.mode,
    set(val) { this.$store.dispatch('updateMode', val); },
  },
```

The key here `this` **fails**

```
   set: val => this.$store.dispatch('updateMode', val),
```

while `this` works

```
   set(val) { this.$store.dispatch('updateMode', val); },
```